# browser doesn't recognize root path constants in urls

Tags: php, url, browser

I'm trying to set a ROOT_PATH constant in a config.php file to make my life easier in development/production when it comes to urls. However, even though my ROOT_PATH constant works in include statements, the same doesn't seem to apply to anchor tags:

_header.php file:

```
<?php
        // if the admin user is logged in:
        if(Login::isLogged(Login::$_login_admin)) { ?>
            <div><a href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>/admin/?page=logout">Logout</a></div>
        <?php
        }
        else {
              ....
```

Firefox gives me this error:
"Firefox doesn't know how to open this address because the protocols (c) isn't associated with any program or isn't allowed in this context".
Chrome does nothing. It doesn't even open the link.

I don't know if this is important, but after giving me the error, the url looks like this in Firefox: `"c:\xampp\htdocs\Tutorials\E-commerce/admin/?page=logout" instead of 'localhost/tutorials/E-commerce/admin/?page=logout'`

I don't understand why this is happening, since the url seems to be ok:

```
"c:\xampp\htdocs\Tutorials\E-commerce/admin/?page=logout"
```

config.php:

```
defined('ROOT_PATH') 
        || define('ROOT_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) .DS."..".DS));

//I've also tried define('ROOT_PATH', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Tutorials\E-commerce'); but it didn't work
```

Also, just in case it's needed, my dirs structure:

```
htdocs
    Tutorials
        E-commerce
            index.php
            classes
            include
                autoload.php
                config.php
            admin
                pages
                static
                template
                index.php
            pages
            static
            template
```

I'm using a single entry-point (I think that's what it is called), as my index.php file includes different files, based on the url. Nevermind! I tried this on other files (located in htdocs), and I still get the same problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yea, browsers are supposed to be accessing things under `localhost`, while the server accesses its own files by accessing the local disk— `C:` in your case. Maybe [`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) is what you want?

Comment: So my method doesn't work? Because the user who posted the following question was able to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517541/root-path-in-xampp (in this case, he's using <img> not <a>..maybe that's the difference). I'll look into your suggestion :)

Comment: You're confusing the browser and the server. The browser must access from a server address like localhost, or google.com. The server can access its own local files. For example, `C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php` can access the file `C:\xampp\htdocs\otherfile.php`, but if you want to do a hyperlink (which is for the browser), you would link to `localhost/otherfile.php`.

Comment: Thanks! That made it much clearer now :)